# AngularJS - Route to a different view on page refresh only if I'm on a certain view

Tags: angularjs

This is how my main js file look like:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller:'loginCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/categories', {
        title: 'Documents',
        templateUrl: 'partials/categories.html',
        controller:'categoryCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/files', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/files.html',
        controller:'filesCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}]);

 myApp.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.location = $location;
});
```

What I need to achieve is that when I'm on the files.html view, when I refresh the page, I need the app to redirect to the categories.html view.

How can that be achieved?

Thanks in advance for your time and suggestion.

**EDIT:**

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.location = $location;

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
      if (!current && next.$$route.originalPath == '/files') {
        $location.path('/categories');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: You probably have to watch for page refresh [take a look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983830/how-can-i-detect-a-page-refresh-in-an-angularjs-single-page-application-without] and route there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, I think you can do $routeProvider.when('....',{...}).when(...).when(...).otherwise(); instead of multiple $routeProvider.when(...); calls

Comment: That was actually very helpful. Thank you! I edited my question to contain the answer.